# Running a function on multiple columns of a pandas dataframe in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have a pandas dataframe and 100 columns from S1 to S100.
There might be other columns in the data frame, but we are interested in these only.
We need to get the number of rows satisfying the condition below.

```
num_of_rows = len(df[df[S1] >= float(cutoff)])
```

Is there a way to do this in parallel for 100 columns and get an array of num_of_rows resulting from each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going parallel is most likely to be more expensive, I would use vectorial code:

```
df.ge(float(cutoff)).sum()
```

If you only want to use `Sx` columns:

```
df.filter(like='S').ge(float(cutoff)).sum()
```

Comment: you mean like this, I guess.  df[['S1','S2',..., 'S100']].ge(float(cutoff)).sum()

Comment: @burcak yes, if you have an explicit list of columns

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Does it return array of results?

Comment: It returns a Series, if you want an array add `.to_numpy()`

Comment: Sure, I got it.